# Is this possible with lists?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm wondering if its possible to make a list like this:
[image: make list like this]

Or should I just use divs to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: One way, I can think of, is to have to adjacent `div` each to acomodate a vertical set of three `li`

Comment: You can also use table for this type of listing.

Comment: @newuser you can use a table but only if the data is tabular data, otherwise its difficult to maintain and a misuse of what the table element is supposed to be used for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possbile with pure CSS (floats) to get a list like:

```
LI1    LI2
LI3    LI4
LI5    LI6
```

but to get:

```
LI1    LI4
LI2    LI5
LI3    LI6
```

you'd need to use javascript or 2 lists with css styling. (EDIT: or as another answer by cale_b mentions, for modern browsers you could use `column-count`)

the css for my first scenario would look something like this:

```
ul { width:400px; overflow:hidden; margin:0; padding:0; }
li { width:200px; float:left; margin:0; padding:0; }
```

adjust your widths, margins and paddings to your liking of course

Comment: I think second scenario can also be achieved with little tweak in LI order and using same code. And more elegantly using nth-child. http://jsfiddle.net/r5G9p/

Answer (score 3):

Sure.  Depends on if you need the items to flow down first in columns, or if it can flow left-to-right.

If left-to-right is OK, just assign a display: block, float: left, and width to the li elements:

```
li {
    display: block;  
    width: 150px;  
    float: left;  
}
```

If you're looking for it to flow down first, then to the right, then there are some techniques for modern browsers involving the css3 column-count (only works in modern browsers):

```
ul {
    -moz-column-count:2; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-column-count:2; /* Safari and Chrome */
    column-count:2;
}
```

Your third option would be to use two lists side-by-side,

Or, as you mention, divs.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could, but two divs with one list each I think would work better.

Answer (score 1):

Easily possible with lists. Have you tried?

It's just a matter of CSS.

Stab in the dark:

```
ul { list-style: none; width: 400px; background: #eee; }
li { display: inline-block; float: left;margin: 10px; width: 158px; background: #eee;border: 1px solid #aaa;height: 100px; }​

<ul>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
</ul>
```

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/axtV5/1/)